# Retrieving Photo urls from facebook graph

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, query-string

I am currently fetching my news feed from facebook from a call to: https://graph.facebook.com/me/home . Objects returned here have a "from" key, that has Name, ID, and sometimes category. I know that I can grab the ID and put /picture on the end to get the url of the picture, but I don't want to have to make an extra call. Does anyone know if there is some flag I can pass in which forces the from object to also have a profile Pic in there too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, I *guess* you can use the `fields` parameter to filter the returned results but you can't extend it...not a method that I know.

BUT you really don't need that, your issue isn't really a problem as long as you have the object ID you can consider that you have the "photo url", this actually has a lot of benefits:

- One less field to store in your DB
- One less element in your arrays to process..etc
- One less request from Facebook AND making the facebook json lighter!

I mean what is the difference between:

```
echo "<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/$user_id/picture' alt='' />";
```

And:

```
echo "<img src='$user_photo' alt='' />";
```

Also, having the photo URL in the json returned doesn't mean that you don't need to make an "*extra call*" to actually get/display the image!

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing this. I didn't know if there was any problem with the fact that it has to redirect, so I hesitated.